# Hover product woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Buenos días, estaba investingando para hacer una tienda online, y necesito saber cómo puedo hacer para que cuando haga hover sobre un producto me muestre las tallas disponibles. Algo similar a lo que se ve en esta web:
http://www.bobbies.com/es/117580-mocassins
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Está disponible este ajuste en el woocommerce añadiendo atributos quiza?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cómo haríais para hacer esto de las tallas? Se admiten sugerencias. !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

en este caso debes de editar tu plantilla, y utilizar las funciones de wordpress que se prestan para esto.

Una vez ubiques el archivo que lista las productos agrega:

`global $product;
$sizes = $product->get_attribute( 'sizes' );`

Así la variable `$sizes`te entregara las tallas de ese producto en especial, así solo basta con organizar el CSS y listo :)